# How to remove components in Rad Studio?

Tags: rad, rad-studio

I've been creating an android application in RAD Studio. But when I try to delete a component like buttons, it says:

> Selection contains a component Button1, introduced in an ancestor and cannot be deleted

Answer (score 0):

First you need to delete the inner components and then the parent.
In this case, remove Button1 and then its parent.